# parse xml file with PHP and I want to delete elements by jQuery bas on user need

Tags: php, jquery, xml

this is my xml file, which is generted automatilcally i want to parse this and then modify the content but first I want to have delete action but it does not work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Guide TotalPages="1">
  <guideTitle>TestMe</guideTitle>
  <guideName>hawreGuide2014030516131719</guideName>
  <Page number="1">
    <content type="Statement">Statment for test</content>
    <content type="Question Type1" option1='op1' option2='op2'>Can you answer?</content>
    <content type="Question Type5" option1="Multiple choice1" option2="Multiple choice2" option3="Multiple choice3" option4="" option5="">Multiple choice</content>
  </Page>
</Guide>
```

this is the php code for parsing it

```
if (file_exists('../xmlpages/hawreGuide2014030516131719.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('../xmlpages/hawreGuide2014030516131719.xml');
           } else {
            exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
        }
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
   {
   echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
   if($child->getName() == 'Page')
   {
       foreach($child->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        echo $value.'<br/>';
        echo"<div id='pageSheet'> "; 

       }
   }

   foreach($child->children() as $subchild)
    {
    echo"<br/><p>";
 echo  "The question is :::<input type='text' value='". $subchild ."'> " . $subchild ."<br>";

        foreach($subchild->attributes() as $key => $value) {
            if($key =='type')
            {
                echo "Key ".$key." Value ".$value.'<br/>'; 
            }
        else
        {
    echo "Key ".$key." Value<input type='text' value='". $value ."'> ".$value.'<br/>'; 
            }

 }
echo"<button class='deleteCon'> Delete</button></p><br/>";      
    }
    echo"</div>";
   }

?>
```

and this the jQuery script but it does not work

```
$(".pageSheet").on("click", ".deleteCon", function () {
            $(this).closest("p").remove(); });
```

any idea, or did I do something wrong? ur helps highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ids and classes.

This `echo"<div id='pageSheet'> ";` and this `$(".pageSheet")` not a same.

Use `echo"<div class='pageSheet'> ";` insteed.